# How to deactivate User with Apex

Tags: apex, user

In my Worker trigger, I'm just trying to set related Users to inactive. Why would I get a MIXED_DML_OPERATION on a simple update on a List of Users?

```
for (User u : [SELECT Id, isActive
               FROM User 
               WHERE WorkerId__c IN :workersSetInactive
               AND isActive = true]) {

  u.isActive = false;
  usersToUpdateInactive.add(u);
}

update usersToUpdateInactive;
```

Here's error I'm getting

```
Worker_Trigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: 
System.DmlException: Update failed. 
First exception on row 0 with id 0051F00000qk4rvQAA; 
first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): User, original object: Worker__c: [] Class.Worker_TriggerHandler.deactivateUsers: line 35, column 1 Class.Worker_TriggerHandler.afterUpdate: line 9, column 1 Class.TriggerHandler.handleTrigger: line 38, column 1 Trigger.Worker_Trigger: line 2, column 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update the Setup object(User) and non setup object(Worker) object in the same transaction which is not supported as per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm).

Mix dml error occurs when a non setup and setup object updated/inserted in same transaction then mix dml occurs.

We can avoid this error using future method.

You can use the future method as below. This is just an example of Future method implementation.

```
@future 
     public static void DeActivateUser(set<Id> workersSetInactive)
     {
         List <User> usersToUpdateInactive = new List<User>();    
         for (User u : [SELECT Id, isActive
         FROM User 
         WHERE WorkerId__c IN :workersSetInactive
         AND isActive = true]) {

u.isActive = false;
usersToUpdateInactive.add(u);
}
update usersToUpdateInactive; 
     }
```

Comment: Not disagreeing in general, but running a future method from a trigger is an anti-pattern. Why? Because in an async context you can only queue a single future method, and in a future context you cannot queue another future. And that means the trigger that calls the future cannot scale in an async context and will fail in future context. I would decouple this using a platform event instead. Though this does have the downside delivery is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks... getting this now: Future methods do not support parameter type of of Map<Id,Worker__c>

Comment: You would have to rely on passing only primitive values or collections of primitive values to future methods, which is why the answer only uses a set of IDs (SObjects are not primitives). But see my point above.

Comment: @PhilW How would you solve for this?

I could satisfy the requirement with a Scheduled Job instead... does this help my situation?

Comment: Could you expound: "I would decouple this using a platform event instead. Though this does have the downside delivery is not guaranteed."

Comment: You can, of course, pass the workersSetInactive ID set to a future and query the users as per this answer. Use of a scheduled job means a potentially significant delay before the users get deactivated. But it is an option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134512/discussion-between-ryan-mcneely-and-phil-w).

Comment: If you define a publish after commit platform event with a field to hold (in string form) the ID of the user to deactivate, and create platform event records in your trigger which you then publish on the event bus, you can write an Apex trigger for this platform event that collects the User IDs and deactivates these Users. Platform events run in a separate transaction so no mixed DML issue is seen.